# Sending email on behalf of Google Apps user (a repost) with GAE

Tags: python, forms, google-app-engine

I apologize first if you just want to point me to an answered question on this topic. I've searched and either I'm not getting it, or my problem is different. I'm trying to create a form for web users at my site to get in contact with me easily. I don't want to have them login, or create an account for them on my site. I just want to be able to fill out the form; name, email, subject and message, and hit send to send it to me. I'm the super admin of the Google apps domain.

main.py

```
# [START imports]
import os
import urllib

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.api import mail

import jinja2
import webapp2

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)
# [END imports]

# [START main_page]
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())

    def post(self):
    name = self.request.get('name')
    message = mail.EmailMessage(to = 'my_google_apps_domain_user@mydomain.com',
                        sender = self.request.get('email'),
                    subject = self.request.get('subject'),
                    body = "From: " + name + " Message: " + self.request.get('message'))
    message.send()

    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())
# [END main_page]

# [START sitemap_page]
class SiteMapPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('sitemap.xml')
        self.response.write(template.render())
# [END sitemap_page]

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage), ('/sitemap.xml', SiteMapPage)], debug=True)
```

index.html snippet on form

```
<form id="contact-form" method ="post">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name">Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required aria-required="true" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                        </span>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" required aria-required="true" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                      <select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required aria-required="true">
                        <option value="na" selected="">Choose One:</option>
                        <option value="service">General Customer Service</option>
                        <option value="suggestions">Suggestions</option>
                        <option value="product">Product Support</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name">Message</label>
                      <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="9" cols="25" required aria-required="true" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-skin pull-right" id="btnContactUs">Send Message</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

I appreciate your help, and if you need any other information, please let me know.

I get an Unauthorized sender server error;

```
Internal Server Error

The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~www-is/1.381224894290286420/main.py", line 31, in post
    message.send()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 1115, in send
    raise ERROR_MAP[e.application_error](e.error_detail)
InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender
```

Answer (score 0):

`sender` email address should be registered as application administrator for GAE project, or you can use something like `any_string@PROJECT_ID.appspotmail.com`. In your case you can simple set `reply_to` argument to user's email address and use sender's email from one of administrators.

Comment: Dmitry, Thank you. my sender email is registered as the owner, but I still get the same error. Where do you set the email to be administrator, is there something there I am missing? Webmaster tools?, Google developer console? Apps console?

Comment: I'm listed as super admin in the apps console.

Comment: The quota is going up for the mail api, as I test the application, but I still get the error message, Unauthorized sender. So, my question now becomes, how do I  check the sender mail's correctly labeled an administrator in the application?